# Install Shield: Delete not empty folder and all its content with a RUL Script function

Tags: installshield

I have a legacy install shield project that installs a software that creates a custom folder structure containing a lot of files and other folder with files and so on.

Now it is mandatory to delete that folder recursiv when deinstalling the application.

So far I found out that this is not possible in the InstallShield UI but I think it can be done with the `RUL Script`.

I come from the Java world and I don't even know what programming/scripting language is used here. I'm basically asking for a code snippet to delete a folder recursiv with a 'RUL function'.

I'd appreciate any help I can get here!

Comment: Markus, what type of Installshield package is this? Is it a basic MSI, a pure InstallScript installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the DeleteDir InstallScript function Markus. If this is a MSI install try the RemoveFile table.

For help on DeleteDir http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield19helplib/Subsystems/installshield19langref/helplibrary/LangrefDeleteDir.htm

For help on RemoveFile table: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371201(v=vs.85).aspx

Hopefully this helps.